# Code is executed in IF statement when condition is not met

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a sheet with over 400 calendar events and I am trying to write a script that will take these events from my spreadsheet and create events for them in my Google Calendar. To prevent the script from duplicating events every time it runs, I am setting the *eventID* as a check in the last column of my spreadsheet. The logic is that if the *startTime* column and *endTime* columns are not blank and the *EventID* column IS blank, then the script should run and create a new event, then log the ID into the last column.

I am finding that the code logs an *eventID* in the last column all the time, which means it creates an event every time, even when the conditions are not met.

```
function createCalendarEvent() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('MasterList');
  var data = sheet.getSheetValues(3, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), 12);
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('*CalendarID*');

  for (var i = 0; i <= sheet.getLastRow(); i++) {
    var title = data[i][0]; //String
    var date = new Date(data[i][1]); //Date
    var startTime = new Date(data[i][9]); //DateTime
    var endTime = new Date(data[i][10]); //DateTime
    var location = data[i][5]; //String
    var status = data[i][11]; //String
    var allDay = data[i][3]; //String

    if (allDay === 'ALL DAY' && status === ''){
      var allDayEvent = calendar.createAllDayEvent(title, date, {location: location});
      sheet.getRange(i + 3, 12).setValue(allDayEvent.getId());
    }
    else if (startTime !== '' && endTime !== '' && status === '' ) {
      var event = calendar.createEvent(title, startTime, endTime, {location: location});
      sheet.getRange(i + 3, 12).setValue(event.getId());
    } 
    else {
      Logger.log('\nRow %s is missing start and/or end time or the event has already been created.\n', i + 3);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What type of event is created ? All-day event or event with correct start and end time ? Try also to log all the values to see what really happened.

Comment: Also, your loop length definition is wrong, data array is shorter than the sheet's last row value. Use data.length in the for loop length definition instead.

Comment: As a modification point except for the for loop, I think that ``data`` of ``var data = sheet.getSheetValues(3, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), 12);`` retrieves 2 more empty rows. If this is what you want, please ignore this modification. If this is not what you want, how about modifying to ``sheet.getLastRow() - 2``? And declaring ``var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow()`` may be also better, because ``sheet.getLastRow()`` is used 2 times in your script.

Comment: And last but not least, you don't need to use newDate to define start time, end time and event date, these values are normally already date objects when you get them from the spreadsheet. If not then you just create date objects with a wrong value ! Try to log newDate('') to see what happens ;) to solve this without risk do the condition check on the data value instead, not on the newly created date objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on suggestions in the comments, I determined that the "empty" cells were being treated at the "zero" date of Google Sheets, which is 12/30/1899 0:00:00. So while I could not see a value in the cell, the code was still grabbing that value. Once I set the condition that the endTime had to be greater than the startTime, it worked out (and flushed out a few errors in the spreadsheet where one of the users indeed entered end times that were before the start time).